# CircularlinkedList generics

Tags: java, generics, generic-list, circular-list

I am experiencing a problem with generics in a CircularLinkedList. I have my CircularLinkedList class, a Node class and a Person class. 
The Node's should contain persons and the CircularLinkedList should contain those nodes. The problem is, that when i try to create my CircularLinkedList in my Test class, i get an error saying:

> Bound mismatch: The type `Node<Person>` is not a valid substitute for
>   the bounded parameter `<E extends Comparable<? super E>>` of the type
>   `CircularLinkedList<E>`

Can you take a look at my generics?

#### CircularLinkedList.java

```
 package cirkulærliste;

    import java.util.Random;

    public class CircularLinkedList<E extends Comparable<? super E>> {

        private Node<E> next;
        private Node<E> start;
        private int size = 0;

        public CircularLinkedList() {
            setNext(null);
        }

        /**
         * tilføjer personer
         * @param p
         */
        public void addPerson(E e) {
            Node<E> newNode = new Node<E>(e, null);
            Node<E> tempNext = next;

            if(next == null){
                next = newNode;
                next.setNext(next);
            } else if(size > 1){

            }
        }

        /**
         * udskriver personerne i den rækkefølge de står i listen
         */
        public void print() {
            Node<E> tempNode = start;
            while (!tempNode.getNext().equals(start)) {
                System.out.println(tempNode);
                tempNode = tempNode.getNext();
            }
            System.out.println(tempNode);
        }

        /**
         * en tilfældig person i den cirkulæreliste vælges som start i listen
         */
        public void randomStart() {
            int size = 1;
            Node<E> tempNode = next.getNext();
            while (!tempNode.getNext().equals(next.getNext())) {
                tempNode = tempNode.getNext();
                size++;
            }
            Random randomizer = new Random();
            int chosen = randomizer.nextInt(size);
            for (int i = 0; i <= chosen; i++) {
                tempNode = tempNode.getNext();
            }
            start = tempNode;
        }

        /**
         * fjerner den person fra listen der ligger count pladser fra start i listen. Personen der fjernes returneres.
         * @param count
         */
        public Node<E> remove(int count) {
            Node<E> tempNode2;
            for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
                next = next.getNext();
            }
            tempNode2 = next.getNext();
            next.setNext(next.getNext().getNext());
            tempNode2.setNext(null);
            return tempNode2; 
        }


        public void setNext(Node<E> next) {
            this.next = next;
        }


        public Node<E> getNext() {
            return next;
        }


        public void setStart(Node<E> start) {
            this.start = start;
        }


        public Node<E> getStart() {
            return start;
        }
    }
```

#### Node.java

```
package cirkulærliste;

public class Node<E> {

    private E element;
    private Node<E> next;

    public Node(){
        element = null;
        next = null;
    }

    public Node(E element, Node<E> next){
        this.setElement(element);
        this.next = next;
    }

    public E getElement() {
        return element;
    }

    public void setElement(E element) {
        this.element = element;
    }

    public Node<E> getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public void setNext(Node<E> newNode) {
        this.next = newNode;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "" + element;
    }

}
```

#### Person.java

```
package cirkulærliste;

public class Person implements Comparable<Person> {

    private String name;
    private int number;

    public Person(String name, int number){
        this.setName(name);
        this.setNumber(number);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "Name: " + name + "  -  " + "Number: " + number;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Person o) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

}
```

#### Test.java

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CircularLinkedList<Person> list = new CircularLinkedList<Person>();

        Node<Person> n1 = new Node<Person>();
        n1.setElement(new Person("Thomas", 1));
        list.addPerson(n1); // Compile error occurs here
    }

}
```

Comment: What line does the compiler error occur at?

Comment: Where's your test class? It is generally a good idea to post the code that is generating the error.

Comment: yeah i know, but i am having a problem with the post.. I cant get it to show the test class. Right now it is showing under the Person class block, which is weird

Comment: There's no reason for the type constraint to be `E extends Comparable<? super E>` – `CircularLinkedList` doesn't compare its elements against one another. Just make the class signature `CircularLinkedList<E>`; with generics, less is more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're writing

```
CircularLinkedList<Node<Person>>
```

in your Test class; but you actually need to be writing

```
CircularLinkedList<Person>
```

---

**Update** for updated question: You also need to change this:

```
Node<Person> n1 = new Node<Person>();
n1.setElement(new Person("Thomas", 1));
list.addPerson(n1); // Compile error occurs here
```

to this:

```
list.addPerson(new Person("Thomas", 1));
```

In general, code that uses `CircularLinkedList` shouldn't refer to `Node`; `CircularLinkedList` uses `Node` internally, but users of the class don't need to worry about that.

Also, it's kind of odd that your generic `CircularLinkedList` class has a method named `addPerson`. Surely it should be called `addElement`, or just `add`?

Comment: if i write it like this:

CircularLinkedList<Person> list = CircularLinkedList<Person>();

it gives me an error at the parenthesis.

Syntax error on token "(", Expression expected after this token

Comment: @ThomasTeilmann: That's because you're missing the keyword `new`. You need to write `CircularLinkedList<Person> list = new CircularLinkedList<Person>();`.

Comment: arg, jebus. Thx dude, ive been programming for 11 hours straight now.. Im soo tired.. Thanks

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. It was such a bad mistake, really.

Comment: @ThomasTeilmann: You mean, something other than what I mentioned in my answer? No, nothing else is wrong. The classes that you posted look fine.

Answer (score 0):

Putting your code into an IDE gives me an error here:

```
Node<Person> n1 = new Node<Person>();
n1.setElement(new Person("Thomas", 1));
list.addPerson(n1);
```

A method `addPerson(E e)` on a collection of type `CircularLinkedList<Person>` expects a `Person` instance as a parameter. Your implementation of `addPerson` even creates a new `Node` instance (as it should), so there's no need to do it in calling code.

This compiles fine:

```
list.addPerson(new Person("Thomas", 1));
```

Comment: yeah, i know.. :) It was just something that were included with a copy paste of a similar test class. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @ThomasTeilmann Could you please post the code that causes actual the error you're asking about, post as little of said code as possible, not post some completely unrelated test code, and also point out where the error occurs?